# UI not responds during copying bulk of files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, timer

I need you to **debug my idea** about this project.

I've written a backup manager project which I give a folder and it copies every file and folder of it to another location and so on.

It works (does the copy job well) but during copying which takes about 1 minute the application UI does not respond. I've heard about threads and I've seen the word parallel programming (just the word and no more), now I want some explanation, comparison and examples to become able to switch my code.

I have done very simple actions with threads before but it was a long time ago and I am not confident enough on threading. Here is my code :

```
private void CopyFiles(string path, string dest)
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dest + "\\" + path.Split('\\')[path.Split('\\').Count()-1]);
    dest = dest + "\\" + path.Split('\\')[path.Split('\\').Count() - 1];
    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(file, dest + "\\" + file.Split('\\')[file.Split('\\').Count() - 1]);
    }
    foreach (string folder in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        CopyFiles(folder, dest);
    }
}
```

I run this in a timer based on a special interval, if I come up using threading, should I omit timer? Lead me, I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not confident with threading enough, I highly recommend you read [Joe Albahari's Threading in C# Tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). Parallel programming is when you do multiple operations in 'parallel' or at the same time (mostly for spreading large amounts of calculations over several CPU or GPU cores). In this case you want threading to make your UI responsive while copying all the files. Essentially, you would have something set out like this: (After you read the threading in C# tutorial)

```
Thread copyFilesThread = new Thread(() => 
{
    CopyFiles(path, dest);
});
copyFilesThread.Start();
```

The UI runs on its own thread. All of the code that is put into your application will run on the UI thread (unless you are explicitly using threading). Since your `CopyFiles` method takes a long time, it will stop the UI until the copying job is completed. Using threading will run the `CopyFiles` on a separate thread to the UI thread, therefore making the UI thread responsive.

Edit: As for your timer, how often does it run?

Comment: It depends, my user decides how often it runs, I actually get it from a textbox. But logically it will be set between a minimum of half an hour and a maximum of 4 hours. should I sleep the thread? or continue using timer?

Comment: @mahditahsildari I would stick with the timer. Sleeping a thread for that long is never good.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to perform an operation in a separate dedicated thread which allows you to know when the thread has completed is by using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

An example of usage is on the page I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a big or unknown amount of files, you should use ThreadPool

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
 {
    CopyFiles(folder, dest);
 });
```

Comment: is it logical to use ThreadPool where you can do the job with a single Thread?

Comment: @mahditahsildari I would say it's never a bad idea

Comment: acutally I'm learning threading by this question, and can you explain me what extra benefit ThreadPool gives me in this case?

Comment: @mahditahsildari if you run a single task in thread pool you have probably no profit, but it's better to run every file.copy as separate thread and put it in thread pool. Once a thread in the pool completes its task, it is returned to a queue of waiting threads, where it can be reused. This reuse enables applications to avoid the cost of creating a new thread for each task. Thread pools typically have a maximum number of threads. If all the threads are busy, additional tasks are put in queue until they can be serviced as threads become available.

Comment: @VladL Don't forget he could be copying hundreds or thousands of files  and the ThreadPool would have to keep on re-using other threads a lot.

Comment: @MatthewRz that is actually very good, at least much better than start hundreds or thousands of threads at once and blow the memory :)

Comment: @VladL Yes but I think the overhead for re-using thousands of threads will slow it down, there would be very few advantages to using the ThreadPool over just using 1 thread. In my opinion.

Comment: @MatthewRz so are we talking about thousands or about one Thread? For thousands there in nearly no other choice. For one - there is no more overhead as ThreadPool is per process and will manage one thread + gui/main thread and other routines.

Comment: @VladL when I test your code I hit this error `The file '*fileAddress*' already exists`, I think it is because of ThreadPool, because when I use simple threading I don't get such error. If I'm wrong then correct me, where else could be the problem?

Comment: @mahditahsildari it's not because of ThreadPool, but because your file already exists, as exception says. You must always check with File.Exists and delete it before. You didn't seen this error because your file didn't exist at that moment, nothing else is possible! Simply use File.Copy(file, dest + "\\" + file.Split('\\')[file.Split('\\').Count() - 1], true);

Answer (score 0):

Background worker can be used to implement asynchronous execution.
This link may help
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20627/BackgroundWorker-Threads-and-Supporting-Cancel